# NextJS render results based on queryparams from external API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Im connecting to a rest API from my NextJS app. It returns results based on a filter in the query string, for example

```
/jobs
/jobs?filter=completed
/jobs?filter=upcoming
/jobs?filter=cancelled
```

I have a few buttons on my NextJS page which when clicked i would like to use these endpoints.

```
import axios from '@/lib/axios'
import useSWR from "swr"
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Jobs = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const queryParams = router.query

    const hasQueryParams = Object.keys(queryParams).length > 0

    const { data: jobsData, error } = useSWR('/jobs', () => 
        axios.get('/jobs')
            .then(response => response.data.data)
    )

    return (
        <>
            <button href="#">Completed</button>
            <button href="#">Upcoming</button>
            <button href="#">Cancelled</button>

            // job data here
        </>
    )
}

export default Jobs
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useSWR hook to fetch data based on the query parameters. You can update the query parameters when a button is clicked, and useSWR will automatically re-fetch the data based on the new query parameters.

```
import axios from '@/lib/axios';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Jobs = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { filter } = router.query;

  const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url).then((response) => response.data.data);

  const { data: jobsData, error } = useSWR(filter ? `/jobs?filter=${filter}` : '/jobs', fetcher);

  const handleFilterClick = (newFilter) => {
    router.push({
      pathname: '/jobs',
      query: { filter: newFilter },
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => handleFilterClick('completed')}>Completed</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleFilterClick('upcoming')}>Upcoming</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleFilterClick('cancelled')}>Cancelled</button>

      {/* Render job data here */}
      {jobsData && jobsData.map((job) => (
        <div key={job.id}>{/* Render job details */}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Jobs;
```

Comment: That seems to be semi wrking, except when i try and use it in a Link .. Im using `<Link
    href="#"
    onClick={() => handleFilterClick('past')}
>
    Past Jobs
</Link>`

and i get `Error: Cancel rendering route`